# Form POST method does not send request to correct route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have following Razor code:

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="Cryptocurrency" asp-action="DeleteWatchedProduct">
    <button type="submit" name="id" value="@providerItem.Item.Id" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</form>
```

and following action

```cs
[HttpPost("watched-product/{id}")]
public IActionResult DeleteWatchedProduct([FromRoute]string id)
{
   return RedirectToAction("WatchedProducts",new
   {
       deletedId = id
   });
}
```

When I hit the `Delete` button, it sends request to `https://localhost:5003/cryptocurrency/deletewatchedproduct` but desired target URL is `https://localhost:5003/cryptocurrency/watched-product/id-is-here`

How can I set it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the [`asp-route-id`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0#asp-route-value) attribute for the `form` tag instead of defining it in the `button`.

> The `asp-route-{value}` attribute enables a wildcard route prefix. Any
> value occupying the {value} placeholder is interpreted as a potential
> route parameter. If a default route isn't found, this route prefix is
> appended to the generated `href` attribute as a request parameter and
> value.

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="Cryptocurrency" asp-action="DeleteWatchedProduct",
    asp-route-id="@providerItem.Item.Id">
```